# ngControl resulting in undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to simply log the ngControl angular object that is bound to the input field to console, so I can see its contents. Below is a very basic example of ngControl, that seems like it should work, however when I try to log to console, I am getting undefined.

Has anyone encountered this? I appreciate any assistance in resolving.

App Component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ContactFormComponent} from './contact-form.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ContactFormComponent],
    template: '<contact-form></contact-form>',
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Contact Form Template

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'contact-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/contact-form.component.html'
})
export class ContactFormComponent{
    log(x) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

Form Template

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input ngControl="firstName" #firstName="ngForm" (change)="log()" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">
            Comment
        </label>
        <textarea ngControl="comment" #comment="ngForm" (change)="log()" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">
        </textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see you importing the FormsModule or any part of @angular/forms that would allow you to use that directive. Do you have an NgModule importing the FormsModule?

Comment: I am following a video tutorial step by step that doesn't import it and it seems to work for him, so I am assuming it is not necessary on that RC? note, he doesn't update to the latest RC until later in the tutorial - and it seems to work for him

Comment: I'd recommend following the official forms tutorial (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html). The RC versions were very fast paced in terms of broad changes, and projects using these pre-release versions are unlikely to work completely using the latest Angular release.

Comment: Note that the `angularjs` tag is for Angular 1.x. If you're using Angular 2, just use the `angular2` tag.

Answer (score -2):

```
#comment="ngForm" => try #comment="Form"
```